# linux with KDE, disable CTRL+F9 combination key

Tags: linux, keyboard, kde

On my linux (ubuntu) with KDE, when i press CTRL+F9 the system shows all the opened windows as miniatures, allowing me to select one by clicking on it. 
Unfortunately, the very same key combination is used by my developing IDE (rubymine) as a debug shortcut (it shows the evaluate expression window, used frequently while debugging).
How can i remove it from the combinations managed by the system?
Moreover, I've noticed that:

1. on the same system, the    ubuntu-native gui (unity) doesn't
   intercept this key combination,    allowing me to have it sent to
   the current application
2. I've tried the following command that I've
   read somewhere:

   ```
      $ xmodmap -pke
   ```

it returns a quite long list of combinations, but the one i'm looking for seems to be not even listed here.

Comment: Have you tried to look at KDE System Settings > Shortcuts and Gestures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `System Settings` -> `Shortcuts and Gestures` -> `Global Keyboard Shortcuts`. From there select KDE component `KWin` and scrol down to `Toggle Present Windows (Current desktop)`